# How to exclude records from mysql query count?

Tags: mysql, count, records

[image]

How can i count all facebook profiles from facebook column?

I used this

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(facebook) FROM members";  
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $fbcount);
```

And it give result 5.

How can i make it to count just 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is simply doing a COUNT on `facebook` column without using any conditions. And therefore the query will return as many records as you have in the table.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM `members`
WHERE `facebook` != '' 
AND `facebook` IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 $query = "Select count(facebook) as Count from members 
 where facebook = 'http://www.facebook.com'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work for me. regards! btw i can't vote.

Comment: @daking963 - The reason is the facebook column will end like this: http://www.facebook.com/some-profile-id

Comment: I think a downvote was unfair here because it was easy to miss in the example on what `facebook` column might contain. In the first quick look, it seemed that it will contain either http://www.facebook.com or nothing. So I think a mere suggestion was fine for daking963 to fix the query